# How to debug an program start2.exe developped in delphi started by another program start1.exe

Tags: debugging, delphi

How to debug an program start2.exe developped in delphi XE4 started by another program start1.exe developped in delphi XE4

I want to debug start2.exe, which is started by Start1.exe via the function API Createprocess.

how should we go about it ?
What options must we validate for the debug to work?

Comment: You can go menu `Run->Attach to Process...`, than pick your `start2.exe` project and it's not depends how you start it. If `start2.exe` not in the list of programs, try to run IDE with admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

In the Delphi IDE open the **start2** project.
Open `Run/Parameters...` menu.
In `"Host Application"` select the complete path of **start1** project:

[image]

Now you can run with `F9`. The IDE run the **start1.exe** application and you are debugging the **start2.exe**.